# Curve segment satisfying $x_{\ell} = x_0 + \int_0^{\ell} \cos (\theta) ds$ and $y_{\ell}= y_0 + \int_0^{\ell} \sin(\theta) ds$ - why?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I want to know why the statement

> Then a curve segment of length $\ell$ satisfies $(x_0, y_0)$ and ending 
>   at $(x_{\ell}, y_{\ell})$ satisfies $x_{\ell} = x_0 +\int_0^{\ell} \cos(\theta) ds$ and $y_l = y_0 + \int_0^{\ell} \sin(\theta) ds$

is true in context of the following:

[image]

Comment: I added the "differential-geometry" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
  \gamma(s) &= \begin{bmatrix} \xi(s) \\ \eta(s) \end{bmatrix} \\
  \gamma'(s) &= \begin{bmatrix} \xi'(s) \\ \eta'(s) \end{bmatrix}
  \tag{tangent vector} \\
  |\gamma'(s)| &= 1
  \tag{arc length parametrization} \\
  \xi'(s)^2+\eta'(s)^2 &= 1\\
  \tan \theta &= \frac{\eta'(s)}{\xi'(s)}
  \tag{slope of tangent} \\
  \begin{bmatrix} \xi'(s) \\ \eta'(s) \end{bmatrix} &=
  \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta \end{bmatrix} \\
  \xi(s) &= x_0+\int_0^{s} \cos \theta \, ds \\
  \eta(s) &= y_0+\int_0^{s} \sin \theta \, ds \\
  x_{\ell} &= \xi(\ell) \\
  y_{\ell} &= \eta(\ell) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Could you please explain why $\xi (s) = x_0 + \int_0^s \cos(\theta)ds$ ?

Comment: Fundamental theory of calculus: $$f(x)=f(a)+\int_{a}^{x} f'(t) \, dt \iff f(x)-f(a)=\int_{a}^{x} f'(t) \, dt$$

Comment: Ah, of course. This was so simple, but I guess I needed someone to explicitly tell me. Thank you for your time.